# Noob Syntax Issue with Semicolon

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to create a forEach loop that creates a http batch request in NodeRed. The formatting of the payload needs to be a JSON object, my function node keeps indicating that I need ; instead of : in the forEach loop at the end.  I know it’s probably something nooby stupid but I can’t seem to figure out what my issue is.

```
var ipaddr =        msg.payload.ipddr[0]
var credentials = msg.payload.auth[0]
var base64 = new Buffer(credentials).toString('base64')

const nameArray = msg.payload.nameArray
const descriptionArray = msg.payload.descriptionArray
const areaArray = msg.payload.areaArray
const useTypeArray = msg.payload.useTypeArray
const addressArray = msg.payload.addressArray
const yearBuiltArray = msg.payload.yearBuiltArray

var createMsg = {};

createMsg.method = "POST";
createMsg.headers = {};
createMsg.headers['authorization'] = 'basic ' + base64;
createMsg.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/JSON";
createMsg.url = "https://" + ipaddr + "/v2/batch";
 
var body =
  {
      "requests":[
          nameArray.forEach((y, i) => {
            {
              "id": nameArray[i]
              "url": "/api/rest/v2/services/site/buildings/" + nameArray[i]
              "key": name
              "use-type": useTypeArray[i]
              "area": areaArray[i]
              "address": addressArray[i]
              "description": descriptionArray[i]
              "year-built": yearBuiltArray[i]
            },
          }
        )
      ]
  };
createMsg.payload = body;
node.send(createMsg);
return null;
```

I would expect it to be ok with each entry in the last for loop like “area”: areaArray[i]

Comment: You can't put a `.forEach()` loop in the middle of an object initializer expression.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a couple of problems with your code.

The `forEach()` method is attempting to create an object with several properties, but it is missing commas between the properties.

You want to use `map()`, instead of `forEach`. If for some reason you would want to keep the `[]` and an `map` method, you would need to spread the results in the this array using `...` operator. But let's assume you don't want to do that:

```js
var body = {
  "requests": nameArray.map((name, i) => { // or [...nameArray.map etc..
    return {
      "id": nameArray[i],
      "url": "/api/rest/v2/services/site/buildings/" + nameArray[i],
      "key": name,
      "use-type": useTypeArray[i],
      "area": areaArray[i],
      "address": addressArray[i],
      "description": descriptionArray[i],
      "year-built": yearBuiltArray[i]
    };
  })
};
```

`forEach()` is used to loop over an array and execute a function for each element of the array. It does not return anything in contrast to `map()` function, which transforms every element to desired shape and returns new array.